# Shared JavaScript File with Different Definitions of a Function Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, design-patterns

I have a 300 line javascript file that sets up jQuery event handlers and other needed functions for a partial view that's used by multiple views within a ASP.NET MVC application.  The event handlers handle 99% of everything identically regardless of which view is using the partial.  This question is about that 1% difference.

Since JavaScript doesn't have interfaces is it safe to define a function to be called by one or more of the event handlers that processes the things that are different in a separate file that is loaded depending on which view is used?  If not, what would be the best way to handle this situation?  In other languages I'd use interfaces and/or abstract classes in this situation.

Example:

**shared file**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //shared variables here for methods
    $(document).on('click', '.selectable-table tbody tr', function() {
        //do shared actions
        mySpecificFunction();
        //finish shared actions (if necessary)
    });
});
```

**Definition1.js**

```
function mySpecificFunction() {
   //do stuff
}
```

**Definition2.js**

```
function mySpecificFunction() {
   //do other stuff
}
```

The views would load the appropriate scripts as such:

```
<script src="definitionX.js"></script>
<script src="sharedScript.js"></script>
```

The "signature" (term being used generously because javascript) of `mySpecificFunction()` would be the same for each definition, but something in my gut is telling me that this is bad practice.  Is there a better/correct way to do this or a design pattern for this purpose?

Comment: If you want to formalized, have you considered Command Pattern? http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/command-design-pattern

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I think this is the route I need to be looking into.  I will admit I don't know many formal design patterns for JavaScript.  Do you have any other resources or can you post an example in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use OOP approach here and you don't need the abstract classes or interfaces for that, instead you can use objects (which are more flexible than in other languages).

For example, you can have a base `View` prototype with shared code and then load specific `view1.js`, `view2.js` where the base prototype will be extended with specific code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // view is a view instance coming from the specific view.js
    view.init();
});

// sharedScript.js, view prototype
var View = {
    init: function() {
        $(document).on('click', '.selectable-table tbody tr', function() {
            // do shared actions
            // ...
            // do specific actions
            this.mySpecificFunction();
        });
    },
    mySpecificFunction: function() {
        //do specific things, can be left empty in the "prototype" object
        return;
    }
};

// view1.js
var view = Object.create(View);
view.mySpecificFunction = function() {
    alert('view 1');
}

// view2.js
var view = Object.create(View);
view.mySpecificFunction = function() {
    alert('view 2');
}
```

And the views would load shared and specific scripts:

```
<script src="sharedScript.js"></script>
<script src="view1.js"></script>
```

This is just a rough idea which can be improved, for example, you may want to concatenate and compress all your js code into the single file for production. In this case the global `view` variable coming from `view1.js`, `view2.js`, etc would become a problem.

An improvement can be some kind of "router" which will detect what view should be instantiated:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    router.when('/', function() {
       view = HomePageView();
    }).when('/about', function() {
       view = AboutPageView();
    });
    view.init();
});
```

Comment: This is exactly the type of thing I was looking for.  Thanks for explaining it so clearly.  I certainly need to start learning some more JavaScript design patterns since I'm not always doing backend work anymore!

Comment: @JNYRanger I would also recommend to look into some of modern frameworks (angular or react). I moved from the web-applications where most of the job was done on the backend to more heavy client-side apps using jQuery and from there to angular on the client and it was really impressive. Basically it allows to easily build the whole UI on the client and your backend can only serve the data in json.

Answer (score 0):

The approach outlined above will work but it's not the best approach in terms of maintainability. Adding one file or another via a script tag to import the specific function 
doesn't necessarily make it clear to another developer that you have actually changed the behaviour of the event handlers in the shared code.

A simple alternative could be that within each view you would wrap the partial view within a containing element that has an identifying css class to differentiate between the behaviour required at that point.

Then assign event handlers individually for those different css classes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //shared variables here for methods     

    $(document).on('click', 'div.type1 .selectable-table tbody tr', function() {
        //do shared actions
        mySharedActions();
        mySpecificFunction1();
        //finish shared actions (if necessary)
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'div.type2 .selectable-table tbody tr', function() {
        //do shared actions
        mySharedActions()
        mySpecificFunction2();
        //finish shared actions (if necessary)
    });
});
```

This would allow you to keep all your specific functions together in one place and makes the changing behaviour predicated by the css class explicit
for future developers to see.